# Dynamic JMS Serializer types

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Is it possible to have one class, with 2 types (1 for serialization and 1 for deserialization) on the same property ?

For instance, I use an API that allow me to send an address as a string, and I receive the same address as an object. Like this:

Request:

```
{
  "address": "12 rue rivoli, 75001 Paris"
}
```

Response

```
{
  "address": {
    "street": "12 Rue de Rivoli",
    "postcode": "75004",
    "city": "Paris",
    "country": "France"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this using the `@Accessor` [Annotation Tag of the JmsSerializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor):

> This annotation can be defined on a property to specify
>   which public method should be called to retrieve, or set the value of
>   the given property:

in your entity this could look like this:

```
# AppBundle/Entity/User
<?php
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Accessor;

class User
{


    /** 
     * @var AppBundle\Entity\Address
     * 
     * @Accessor(getter="getAddressAsString",setter="setAddress") 
     */
    private $address;

    // ...
    public function getAddressAsString()
    {
        return sprintf('%s, %s %s', $this->address->getStreet(), $this->address->Postcode(), $this->address->getCity()),
    }

    public function setAddress(Address $address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this error: `You must define a type for User::$address.`

Comment: Did you try to add the following annotation on `User::$address` property:
`@JMS\Type("...")`?

Comment: The blocker here is that you can't define different types for serialization/deserialization. I'm currently struggling with similar issue, no solution found so far :(

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a solution which worked for me:

1. Define a type which you will serialize field into, i.e.

   /**

   - @var string
   - - @Type("string")
       */
       private $address;
2. Implement subscriber/listener on `serializer.pre_deserialize` event, i.e.

   ```
   class MyPreDeserializationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
   {
       public static function getSubscribedEvents()
   {
       return [
           [
               'event' => 'serializer.pre_deserialize',
               'method' => 'onPreDeserialize',
               'class' => Video::class,
               'format' => 'json',
           ]
       ];
   }

   public function onPreDeserialize(PreDeserializeEvent $event)
   {
       $data = $event->getData();
       $data['address'] = implode(', ', $data['address']);
       $event->setData($data);
   }
   ```

   }